# Custom initializer in subclass of UIImageView - is it necessary to override initWithImage or initWithFrame initializers?

Tags: objective-c, ios, initialization

My class is subclass of UIImageView. I create my custom initializer like this

```
@interface FishView : UIImageView
@end

@implementation FishView

- (id)initWithFishType:(FishType)fishType {

    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        //my custom initialization
    }
    return self;

}
```

Is it necessary to override initWithImage?

```
- (id)initWithImage:(UIImage)image
{
    self = [super initWithImage:image];
    if (self) {
        [self initWithFishType:FTNone];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only if you plan to call initWithImage in your code and want it to do something special.

Comment: First thank you for your quick answer. Perhaps I mix it up with overriding designated initializers for custom class.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to override if you want extra functionality in there.

But if I am reading your question as: "I need custom init functionality, shall it go in `initWithImage` or `initWithFrame`? then the answer is more complicated. Then you would actually need to override a bunch of initializers, see

- [What if a class has no documented designated initializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13146901/what-if-a-class-has-no-documented-designated-initializer/19235814#19235814)

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 2, the only necessary initializer for `UIImageView` subclasses is

```
required init?(coder: NSCoder) { super.init(coder: coder) }
```