# What if a class has no documented designated initializer?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am looking for general guidance on how to handle this situation. Here is a specific example.

I am subclassing UIImageView and I want to override initWithImage to add my own initialization code after having the super class init itself with the supplied image.

However, there is no documented designated initializer for UIImageView, so which super class initializer should I call to ensure my subclass is correctly initialized?

If a class does not designate an initializer, do I:

1. Assume that it is safe to call any of the class's (UIImageView) initializers?
2. Look to the super class (UIView) for the designated initializer?

In this case it seems #1 would be the answer as it makes sense to do the following in my overridden initializer:

```
- (id)initWithImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    self = [super initWithImage:image];
    if (self) {
        // DO MY EXTRA INITIALIZATION HERE
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: That looks fine to me. You are calling the superclass' initializer. What is the issue? Objective-C does not provide a mechanism to call the initializer of a designated superclass. (AFAIK)

Comment: UIImageView would be your superclass.  You can call (with `super`) any valid initializer of that class, including initializers that it may inherit (though some of them may not make sense).

Comment: This does indeed work fine, but my question is more general. My understanding is that a subclass should always call the super class's designated initializer, but how do I know what the designated initializer is if it is not documented? Is it safe to call any initializer in the super class if nothing is marked as "designated"?

Comment: Dunno what you mean by "designated".  You must call *an initializer** of the superclass, but there's no single one that's "designated".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UIImageView has two initializers, so you may want to make sure that your subclass handles both of these initialization paths.

You could simply declare that `-initWithImage:` is *your* designated initializer, and all other initializers are not supported.

Further, you could implement `-initWithImage:highlightedImage:` and throw an exception to indicate that it's not supported.

Alternatively, you could declare `-initWithImage:highlightedImage:` as your designated initializer, and have `-initWithImage:` call your designated initializer.

Or, you may find that your `-initWithImage:` initializer is called regardless of whether your class is initialized with `-initWithImage:` or `-initWithImage:highlightedImage:`.

Comment: Darren, you stated that UIImageView has 2 initializers, but how do I know which is the designated initializer of UIImageView? or do they both act as designated initializers if neither is marked as "designated"?

Comment: UIImageView does not have a designated initializer (perhaps because the second initializer wasn't added until iOS 3.0).  If it did, then that's the initializer you would typically override and that would cover all the bases.  But since it does not have a designated initializer you probably want to handle both initializers and direct them both to your own designated initializer.  Otherwise, if someone inadvertently calls an initializer that you do not support, that could produce bugs that are difficult to track down.

Comment: @Darren - OK, you're apparently using "designated" in this case to mean the `init` method that's described in the spec as being the "parent" (my term) of the other `init` methods of the class.  For instance there may be a `initWithX:` method and an `initWithX:andY:` method.  Commonly the first (which is a "convenience" method) would call the second, so you only need to override the second method.  The spec may or may not tell you this.  If not you need to override all `init` methods that *might* be called when using your class, but if you know only one is used just override that.

Comment: @HotLicks, you need to search Apple's docs for the term "designated initializer". It's not some made-up term. It's an [important concept in Cocoa](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Initialization/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH6-SW3).

Answer (score 4):

UIImageView documentation is terrible. It shows two initializers but you can get in to situations where neither of them is called. For example, I am using IB and only `initWithCoder:` gets called.

```
- (id)init
{
    return [super init];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    return [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    return [super initWithFrame:frame];
}

- (id)initWithImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    self = [super initWithImage:image];
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithImage:(UIImage *)image highlightedImage:(UIImage *)highlightedImage
{
    self = [super initWithImage:image highlightedImage:highlightedImage];
    return self;
}
```

The only correct way to subclass UIImageView is to subclass ALL initializers AND each subclass may ONLY call a parent's initializer with the same name. For example:

`subclass -init` can call `UIImageView -init` but it cannot call `UIImageView -initWithCoder:`.

Yes, it's a real pain that there is no designation.

Comment: that's a common issue--if the object is being loaded from a NIB, `-initWithCoder:` will be called. So you often have to override that as well.

Comment: I dont' believe this approach is safe. Since none of the initializers is designated, you can't know that a call to `super`'s won't call back up to your override of another one. If they were not trivial, then you might do work twice that shouldn't be done twice. (If they were trivial, you just wouldn't implement any of them.)

Answer (score 2):

The danger when there's no designated initializer is that any of the initializers you might invoke could do its work in terms of one of the other initializers. In that case, it might accidentally call into one of your overrides, which won't work the way it's expected to.

If your class has exactly one initializer and it's an override of a superclass initializer, then it's safe for it to invoke the initializer that it overrode. That's because there's no chance that the super initializer will (directly or indirectly) re-enter itself, so there's no chance that it will re-enter your override.

Your class could also implement any number of initializers so long as *none* of them have the same name as *any* of the ones from the superclasses. Since your names are unique, there's no chance that any of the superclass initializers will call into them accidentally.

Answer (score 1):

Every class which derives from `NSObject` has `init` method as one initializer which will do the initializing process for that object. So in case you are not sure, you can always use `self = [super init]` in your custom initializer. Considering the fact that `UIImageView` has two initializers provided by apple, you might have to override both of them or throw an exception to the user that they cant use this method(Not recommended).

For eg:-

```
- (id)initWithCustomParam:(NSString *)param {

    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.myparam = param;
    }
    return self;
}
```

And then you can implement other initializers as,

```
- (id)initWithImage:(UIImage *)image {

    if (self = [self initWithCustomParam:@"default value"]) {
        self.image = image;
    }
    return self;
}
```

or define,

```
- (id)initWithImage:(UIImage *)image customParam:(NSString *)string {

    if (self = [self initWithCustomParam:string]) {
        self.image = image;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach is to be lazy. 
You can use methods like viewDidLoad or viewDidMoveToSuperview to do some setup. It really depends on when the setup is important.

Comment: This does not at all answer the question.

Comment: Sure it does. It's a place to do setup lazily.